# Why is using v-for different from placing every item separately in this case? Also Bootstrap content centering

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I was experimenting with my newly acquired knowledge of Vue and Bootstrap when I ran on a behaviour that I couldn't explain.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" class="text-center">
    <p v-html="mensagem"></p>
    <button v-for="tipo in tiposJogadas" class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe(tipo)">{{ tipo }}</button>

    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "column-sm-12" class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="reset()">Reiniciar</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: result with v-for]

Renders three buttons on glued on the other. Whileas if I replace the v-for statement for three button statements like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" class="text-center">
    <p v-html="mensagem"></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe('pedra')">Pedra</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe('papel')">Papel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe('tesoura')">Tesoura</button>

    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "column-sm-12" class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="reset()">Reiniciar</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: result without v-for]

It renders everything perfectly. I don't understand why, since when I inspect the final elements in both scenarios they are the same.

I wasn't gonna ask, but I also couldn't manage to center the red reset button. Since I'm already asking a question, it'd be nice to know why what I've tried doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because the line returns in the HTML are adding whitespace between the buttons. `v-for` isn't. `v-for` is rendering the same as...

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <p v-html="mensagem"></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe('pedra')">Pedra</button><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe('papel')">Papel</button><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="escolhe('tesoura')">Tesoura</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column-sm-12">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="reset()">Reiniciar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could add a margin-right (`mr-1`) to each button...

`<button v-for="tipo in tiposJogadas" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" @click="escolhe(tipo)">{{ tipo }}</button>`

https://www.codeply.com/go/pXOPYAA8St